# Get a portion of text delimited by cariage return with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like:

```
This patch requires:

Patch 1.10-1
Patch 1.11-2

Notes:
```

I want to extract

```
Patch 1.10-1
Patch 1.11-2
```

with the following regex:

```
This patch requires\:[\r\n](.*)[\r\n]Notes\:
```

But nothing is matched.

Why ?

Comment: `[\r\n]` > `[\r\n]+` and use a **DOTALL modifier** or `.` will not match across line breaks. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I97ebV/2), use `'~This patch requires:\R+(.*?)\R+Notes:~s'` and grab `$match[1]`.

Comment: I used `This patch requires\:[\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+Notes\:` but same thing, nothing returned

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: PHP ... I tested in regex.com and seems if I switch to Single Line option then works otherwise not...

Comment: Why not `This patch requires\:\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*Notes\:`?

Comment: [See this working](https://regex101.com/r/Jjv1LP/1)

Comment: Not working without `/This patch requires\:[\s\S]*?Notes\:/gi` , I have to add `s` for single line like: `/This patch requires\:[\s\S]*?Notes\:/gis`

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, `single line` option makes difference

Comment: Single Line option or `DOTALL` is required because you are `.*` that is supposed to match multiline string. Without `s` you can use `[\s\S]*?` also

Comment: You don't need `s` flag if you don't use `.` in your regex. Hence `[\s\S]`.

Comment: `This patch requires\:[\s\S]*?Notes\:` does not capture the text I wish. It captures everything.

Comment: Add capturing group then. See my earlier comment edit.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/I97ebV/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But nothing is matched.

DOT `.` doesn't match newline characters so `.*` doesn't go beyond one line. For that you need to set DOTALL `s` modifier on or try an alternative `[\s\S]` (which literally means any character without any exception).

```
preg_match('~This patch requires:\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*^Notes:~m', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Note: don't use greedy-dot (`.*`) if multiple matches are going to occur instead go lazy `.*?`

By the way this is supposed to be the most efficient regex you may come across:

```
This patch requires:\s+((?:(?!\s*^Notes:).*\R)*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fy0r8c/1)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of alternative solutions:

```
^\QThis patch requires:\E\R+
\K
(?:^Patch.+\R)+
```

---

This says:

```
^\QThis patch requires:\E     # match "This patch requires:" in one line and nothing else
\R+                           # match empty lines + newlines
\K                            # "Forget" what's left
(?:^Patch.+\R)+               # match lines that start with "Patch"
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$regex = '~
    ^\QThis patch requires:\E\R+
    \K
    (?:^Patch.+\R)+
         ~xm';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $your_string_here, $matches)) {
    // do sth. with matches
}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5x4k5T/4/) (and mind the `verbose` and `multiline` modifier!).

Answer (score 0):

What about `(?<=[\r\n])(.+)(?=[\r\n])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmMN1U/3)

Comment: Note that `(?=[\r\n]+)` will work the same as `(?=[\r\n])` since `.*` is a greedy subpattern. Trimming will be required as an additional step.

Comment: thanks, can you edit ?

Comment: I have. Still, what do you mean by "what about"? Answers are helpful when you explain the approach, and here, you are using quite a different approach than OP has. You have two matches now, while OP expects to extract a single 1+-line string.

Comment: You right , I can speak English a little ,so what should I use?

Comment: [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/I97ebV/3).